# Postgresql alter table column type to unique not null

Tags: postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT ...
```

I want to alter column email to add its type as UNIQUE NOT NULL in Postgresql and get this error. Can you explain to me what's wrong?

Comment: I believe it is `varying(50)` not` varchar(50)`.

Comment: @Dan: no, `varchar(50)` is fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot create 2 constraints with one single statement. And you have to use PostgreSQL syntax.

```
alter table users alter column email set not null;
alter table users add constraint email_unique unique (email);
```